# Where is the website which allows me to set up a daily learning schedule?

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study, internet

In the past I have used a website to set up a daily learning schedule for Nach although the program there will allow any daily learning schedule and review.

But I cannot find it again - not even by searching Mi Yodeya!
Please help.

Comment: http://dailynach.com/about/

Comment: @GershonGold Thanks. The website I am seeking allows you to set up your own pace through whatever text you are learning. dailynach.com has the punishing 1 chapter a day program.

Comment: https://koveah.org/

Answer (score 1):

I found it! Hope the information is valuable to others. 
See http://dafyomireview.com/ and go to "advanced review programs".

Comment: also this http://dafyomireview.com/index.php?seriesid=3 simpler version